# Google Analytics - how to get value of session per country?

Tags: google-analytics

The Audience -> Geo -> Location page of Google Analytics shows total revenue that all the users from a certain country have generated. How do I get it to show value per session, i.e. "total revenue from country" / "number of users from country"?

Ideally it would be better to calculate average LTV per session per country, but if it's impossible, that's ok.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near the top left of the Location report you can change the Metric Group from the default Summary set of columns to Ecommerce, which then includes `Per Session Value` as a column.

[image: Screenshot of Location GA report with metric group tabs]

If you wish you had a version of the location report that shows `Per Session Value` along with some columns that are not in the Ecommerce metric group, you can click Edit near the top right of the location report window and it will save a copy as a custom report (opening the Create Custom Report screen shown below), that you can then shift around however you'd like.

[image: Screenshot of part of custom report editing screen]

You could also add a column for `Revenue Per User`, although this is not the LTV version shown in the Audience > Lifetime Value report. Instead it will just combine revenue by user within the date range you're using to view the report.

If you have an idea for a computation you'd like to make and have available as a report column, and it's not already a metric, you can set up a calculated metric under Admin > View > Calculated Metrics (you can add, subtract, multiply, or divide one metric by another), and that metric will be available in a custom report as well.

True Lifetime Value is difficult in GA for privacy reasons, like anything that potentially pulls out per-user information, but hopefully this will get you closer to the numbers you're interested in.